# nightwatch.js: global before and after hooks

Tags: nightwatch.js

Below is my `globals.js` this is lying in `root/lib` directory.

```
module.exports = {

    beforeEach: function (browser) {

        browser.init();
        browser.login('admin');
    },

    afterEach: function (browser) {
        browser.logout();
        browser.end();
    },
}
```

Below is my test file, lying in root/test

```
var util = require('../../lib/globals.js');

module.exports = {



    'user login': function (browser)
    {


        // verify login, then logout
        headerPage.verifyAuthentication();

        browser.logout();
        browser.end();

    }

};
```

But test not at all running `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. I want these two run before and after each test, without putting these functions in each test file as there will be more than 100 test files.

I can't use `mocha` or `grunt` now, as per client's instructions. Please let me know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try next snippets:

`globals.js`

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  return Object.assign({}, options || {}, {
    beforeEach(browser) {
      // common
      browser.init();
      browser.login('admin');
      // custom
      if (options.beforeEach) {
        options.beforeEach.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    },

    afterEach() {
      // custom
      if (options.afterEach) {
        options.afterEach.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      // common
      browser.logout();
      browser.end();
    }
  });
}
```

test file

```
var module = require('../../lib/globals.js');
module.exports = module({
    'user login': function (browser) {
        // verify login, then logout
        headerPage.verifyAuthentication();

        browser.logout();
        browser.end();
    }
});
```

I didn't run that code ( we use modified version ), but the idea is -- collect all `beforeEach`/`afterEach` from global module and from concrete test ( possible you need to change order for common/custom parts )

Comment: It didnt work. I am using JetBrains' Webstorm(blackboard theme). When I was using `beforeEach` and `afterEach` both were appearing grey color , means they aren't used anywhere in project. But now when I am trying `before` and `after` they appear green means they are used somewhere. However none of those still get executed. Is there any implementation of those, in any nightwatch.js sample project lying on in `git`.

Comment: @paul can you share repo with your test?

Comment: and you shouldn't think that if something is "grey" / "green" that code used or not - check it with running / debug, WebStorm is cool, but something it mistakes

Comment: Can I share it on Team Viewer or Skype?

Comment: @paul skype: vasil.vanchuk